# segmentation fault when I'm trying to find out the index of a particular column of CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv, segmentation-fault, substring, strtok

I'm trying to find out the index of a particular column of the CSV file.
And thats what I did: but for some reason, it's giving me segmentation fault.

```
void indexOfColumn(char *column) {
    int columnNumber = 0;
    char buff[1024];
    
    char *header = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024); 

    //read the first line
    fgets(buff, 1024, inFile);
    header = strtok(buff, ",");

    while(header != NULL || strcmp(header, column) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", header);
        header = strtok(NULL, ",");
        columnNumber++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", columnNumber);
}
```

I printed out the char array(header) inside the while loop and looks like it's working, loop stops when it matches with the particular column given in the parameter. But then the segmentation fault comes. It doesn't print the columnNumber I'm printing outside the loop.

Comment: What line does the segfault refer to?  What other details about the segfault do you know?

Comment: how to check the details

Comment: `while(header != NULL || strcmp(header, column) == 0){` --> `while(header != NULL && strcmp(header, column) == 0){` you want "and"  instead of "or", otherwise you call  `strcmp` with a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: `header = malloc(...)` followed by `header = strtok(...)` leads to a *memory leak* as you loose the original pointer returned by `malloc`. You can never pass this pointer to `free`. You don't even need the `malloc` call.

Comment: Just to add on to those thoughts: why is `header` dynamically allocated? Nothing is returned, so this memory doesn't _need_ to remain valid beyond the scope of `indexOfColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this memory allocation produces a memory leak

```
char *header = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
```

because the pointer is reassigned

```
header = strtok(buff, ",");
```

And the condition of the while loop must be changed the following way

```
int columnNumber = 0;

while(header != NULL && strcmp(header, column) != 0){
    printf("%s\n", header);
    header = strtok(NULL, ",");
    columnNumber++;
}

if ( header == NULL ) columnNumber = -1;
```

Pay attention to that indices in C start from 0.

Comment: Memory leak is inherent here - there is no memory free attempt and the local pointer is lost when leaving the func, regardless of internal reassignment.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The memory leak is produced by the reassignment of the pointer because the address of the allocated memory after that is lost.

Comment: The address is lost either way upon exiting the function. Reassignment is secondary here, leak would've occurred with or without it the way the code is written

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The reassignment is the only reason of the memory leak because after that the address of the allocated memory is lost and the memory can not be freed. And it is totally unimportant whether the function was exited or not.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername A memory leak is related to a situation when the program is unable to free a dynamically allocated memory.  Such a situation occurs  when you have no address of the allocated memory and hence are unable to access it.  In the code in the question such a situation occurs after reassigning the pointer that pointed to a dynamically allocated memory. Starting from this point you are unable to access the allocated memory and free it. That is the event of forming of a memory leak occurred in the time when the pointer was reassigned.

Comment: Pointer overriding is an implementation bug. It's superseded by the design bug and hence it's secondary - there is clearly no intention to even attempt to free the memory, either correctly or incorrectly. Fixing the pointer override won't eliminate the memory leak. In fact, it won't affect it in any way.